# Sklearn pipeline with LDA and KNN

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, knn

I try to use `LinearDiscriminantAnalysis` (LDA) class from sklearn as preprocessing part of my modeling to reduce the dimensionality of my data, and after applied a KNN classifier. I know that a good pratice is to use pipeline to bring together preprocessing and modeling part.

I also use the method `cross_validate` to avoid overfitting using cross validation. But when I build my pipeline, and pass it to the `cross_validate` method, it seems that only LDA is used to classify my data, since LDA can be used as a classifier too.

I don't understand why, it is like since the LDA can predict the class, it just use it without the KNN or something like that. I may be using the `Pipeline` class wrong.

Below you can find the code with the pipeline (LDA + KNN) and a version with just LDA, the results are exactly the same. Note that when I transform (reduce) the data before, and use the reduced data into a `cross_validate` method with KNN my result are way better.

```
# Define the pipeline to use LDA as preprocessing part
pipeline2 = Pipeline([
    ('lda', lda),
    ('knn', knn)
])

# Use stratified cross validation on pipeline (LDA and KNN) classifier
result_test = pd.DataFrame(cross_validate(
    pipeline2,
    X_train_reduced,
    y_train,
    return_train_score=True,
    cv=3,
    scoring=['accuracy']
))

# Get mean train and test accuracy
print(f"Mean train accuracy: {result_test['train_accuracy'].mean():.3f}")
print(f"Mean validation accuracy: {result_test['test_accuracy'].mean():.3f}")
```

Mean train accuracy: 1.000
Mean validation accuracy: 0.429

```
# Define the pipeline to use LDA as preprocessing part
pipeline2 = Pipeline([
    ('lda', lda),
    #('knn', knn) THE KNN IS COMMENT IN THIS CASE!!
])

# Use stratified cross validation on pipeline (LDA and KNN) classifier
result_test = pd.DataFrame(cross_validate(
    pipeline2,
    X_train_reduced,
    y_train,
    return_train_score=True,
    cv=3,
    scoring=['accuracy']
))

# Get mean train and test accuracy
print(f"Mean train accuracy: {result_test['train_accuracy'].mean():.3f}")
print(f"Mean validation accuracy: {result_test['test_accuracy'].mean():.3f}")
```

Mean train accuracy: 1.000
Mean validation accuracy: 0.429

Note that the data used is quiet complex, it is from MRI images, and it has been already reduced using PCA to filter noise on images.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What hyperparameters have you used for the LDA and KNN?  How many classes does your target have, and what is the shape of `X_train_reduced`?

Comment: I used the default parameters for both LDA and KNN. I have 3 classes as target, and the shape of X_train_reduced is (2451, 2048).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is reasonable behavior, though not guaranteed to happen.  The `LDA.transform` is reducing to the top two (`=n_classes-1`) dimensions in its internal model, and the 5-NN model then ends up predicting nearly the same way as the full `LDA.predict` (I guess because the next most important dimensions don't add much?).  If you pressed it, you might find that the `KNN` has wavier prediction thresholds than the nice linear ones from the `LDA`, but since the `LDA` can already perfectly predict the training set, that doesn't cause much difference.

That said, a test accuracy of 0.43 is quite a lot lower.  I suppose that could be because the top two dimensions in LDA, while really good for separating the training set, aren't very good on the test set (for at least some of the fold-splits).  I'd be curious to know how different the top two dimensions actually are across folds.

> Note that when I transform (reduce) the data before, and use the reduced data into a `cross_validate` method with KNN my result are way better.

That's due to data leakage: the `LDA` got to see the entire training set, leaking information about the test folds to each KNN.  Related to the previous paragraph, the top two dimensions selected are good for *all* of the fold-splits.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this response ! I no longer have the detailled result across folds, but I think it was nearly the same for each test, around 0.4.